# DefaultHttpClient is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio

DefaultHttpClient is not supported in API 23 using Marshmallow 6.0 version and Build Tools Version is: 23.0.3

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair>params) {
        try {
            if(method == "POST") {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else if(method == "GET") {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
        }
    }
```

There has been cut mark on the DefaultHttpClient.
Please tell me the way to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is no longer supported on Android API level 23. You have to use `URLConnection`. If you wish to use it, add the following to the `build.gradle`

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Here is the announcement:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: I already added the above use library in my build.gradle but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AniketSaxena Nerd's answer and  **compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'**  add in to your dependency it should work

Comment: It gave me error Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0

Comment: @AniketSaxena OkHttp 2.0 is outdated. You should be using this in your gradle file: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'`

Comment: @Nerd please provide me the link to download this library 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp: 3.4.1'

Comment: you need to include `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1` in the `dependencies` in your `build.gradle`. there is no link to download.

Comment: @Nerd I got the error during the execution of the above library and that is: Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1
<a href="openFile:D:/Core Java/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a> ,Please tell me how to remove this error..... Ni

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. Now use `HttpUrlConnection`.

visit this for more detail about [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

**Example :** to retrive data from url

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

Visit this also here is full Example of `Get` and `Post` method Using `HttpUrlConnection`.

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-post-and-get-request-using-httpurlconnection/

Comment: How to use HttpUrlConnection in the aforementioned code? Please guide me the way to do that.

Comment: As I have inserted the use library in my build.gradle file

Comment: @AniketSaxena see I post the link visit this.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is no more supported , know if you want to work with it you have to downgrade your API level, but if i have to give you an advice you can use other libraries like `Volley` or `Retrofit`.